# (in R) How to use sentiment dictionary lexicon for Spanish and Portuguese?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I would like to make the following code work for Spanish and Portuguese :

Get a French sentiment dictionary lexicon with positive/negative terms, negators, amplifiers and deamplifiers.

Here is my code:

```
load(file("https://github.com/sborms/sentometrics/raw/master/data-raw/FEEL_fr.rda"))
load(file("https://github.com/sborms/sentometrics/raw/master/data-raw/valence-   raw/valShifters.rda"))
polarity_terms <- rename(FEEL_fr, term = x, polarity = y)
polarity_negators <- subset(valShifters$valence_fr, t == 1)$x
polarity_amplifiers <- subset(valShifters$valence_fr, t == 2)$x
polarity_deamplifiers <- subset(valShifters$valence_fr, t == 3)$x
```

I struggle finding equivalents for these languages and don't really understand how I am supposed to recode `polarity_terms`, `polarity_negators`, `polarity_amplifiers`, `polarity_deamplifiers`.

Comment: maybe see https://github.com/JoseCardonaFigueroa/sentiment-analysis-spanish/tree/master/data